# Oracle APEX a valid option?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

We have a PHP/Symfony web application which we use to kick start some procedures on the Oracle DB manually. Sometimes parameters are passed to the procedures: either as a free text box or by drop down which is filled dynamically (eg. SELECT DISTINCT name FROM mytable). Before the webapp did more and was more complex, but now it's really only about start procedures manually. (well, there is also user and rights management: eg. User A can only start procedure A and User B only procedure B).

Now the question is if this solution is still a good option or if it would be better to switch to a solution using Oracle APEX directly on the Oracle server.

So here I've got some questions

- Does anybody know APEX and used it before? Comments? What do you
  think of it?
- Is is basically suited for such a task? What would
  we have to think of as well? What is all needed?
- If yes, how much effort would be needed
  for such a solution (max. 20 User, max. 20 procedures in in 6
  categories)?
- What about maintenance?

Comment: Unfortunately this question is not a good fit for Stack Overflow. Questions should have a definitive answer and therefore cannot be discursive; see the [faq].

Comment: What problem would you be solving by moving to Apex?

Comment: ApEx is a solid tool and suitable for most purposes.  But I agree with David: you don't really seem to have a good business case for re-writing your app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You phrased it open en in that regard i agree with @Ben.
However, what you seem to be looking for looks like it could be very easily implementend in Apex. Form pages created on procedures will automatically generate the required page items and a process calling the procedure.
If you have packages, you can easily mimick that behaviour as you can just create the required page items, and a process that passes those values to a packaged procedure or function.
What you'd need is an apex installation on your database, and a listener (the embedded plsql gateway, the standalone apex listener, or some other http server).
The effort required wouldn't be much. Creating pages and items is not all that hard, and can be done in a declarative way. If all you know is PLSQL, you could still find your way in apex without having to worry to hard about html and/or javascript at first.
If all you need (at least, right now) are some forms which call procedures/packages, the only maintenance you should do is to adjust page items and processes as you alter procedure calls in the database.

If you're really interested, simply go to apex.oracle.com and request a workspace. Take the 2-day developer guide found under the documentation. This will give you at least some idea of the how and what, and you'll see some of what apex has to offer. In your requested workspace will also be a demo application (products) which you can look into, packaged demo applications,... You have access to an own schema too, which can be accessed through the sql browser. Create a procedure! Then create a new application/page, and base it on the procedure: see if you like what you see.